# Python key, value and increment in for loop with dictionary.items()

Tags: python, dictionary

I am looking for a way to get the current loop iteration while looping though a key, value pair of dictionary items.

currently i am using enumerate() to split it into iteration, tuple(key, value) however this requires using tuple indexes to split it back out.

```py
mydict = {'fruit':'apple', 'veg':'potato', 'sweet':'haribo'}

for i, kv in enumerate(mydict.items()):
    print(f"iteration={i}, key={kv[0]}, value={kv[1]}")
#>>> iteration=0, key=fruit, value=apple
#>>> iteration=1, key=veg, value=potato
#>>> iteration=2, key=sweet, value=haribo
```

what I am looking for is a better method to replace the following:

```py
i = 0
for key, value in mydict.items():
     print(f"iteration={i}, key={key}, value={value}")
     i+=1
#>>> iteration=0, key=fruit, value=apple
#>>> iteration=1, key=veg, value=potato
#>>> iteration=2, key=sweet, value=haribo
```

I do not want to give up user assigned keywords for the dictionary just to include iteration. I am hoping to find a solution similar to (psudo-code):

```py
for key, value, iteration in (tuple(mydict.items()), list(mydict.keys()).index(k)):
```

Comment: Just need parentheses: `for i, (key, value) in enumerate(mydict.items()):`

Comment: In f-strings you could do `f'{key=}'` instead of `f'key={key}'`. Related SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57225950

Comment: [Python can unpack nested tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17641038/12892)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the (key, value) in brackets:

```
mydict = {'fruit':'apple', 'veg':'potato', 'sweet':'haribo'}

for i, (key, value) in enumerate(mydict.items()):
    print(f"iteration={i}, key={key}, value={value}")
```